# Collection not showing its values with .find()

Tags: mongodb

I have added some data to my mongodb database `portal_db`.

On mongo, after `use portal_db`, when I type `show collections`, it does show my collections `acs` and `tab0007`, however, when I try to see the values of my collections using `portal_db.acs.find()` or `portal_db.tab0007.find()`, mongo returns the following error message:

```
2019-05-12T17:05:16.551+0000 E QUERY    [js] ReferenceError: acs is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `db.collection.find()`, where `db` is literally just "db" and `collection` is the collection name.

So `db.acs.find()` or `db.tab0007.find()` (after `use portal_db`)